# Find out the proxy server used by WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium

I run selenium WebDriver with a proxy.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="'94.242.58.108:1448'"
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Driver know which proxy server it is using now. 
Could you tell me how to find out the used proxy server?

I need this information in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the java doc http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html
 we have getHttpProxy() to retrieve the proxy.

```
Proxy p=new Proxy(); // used at the start to set proxy and pass to chrome options and driver

System.out.println(p.getHttpProxy()); // to get proxy when required.
```

Comment: the object is of WebDriver class, not Proxy. Not working, unfortunately.